# Implementar ação para o botão salvar

Tags: java, swing

Sou novato em programação e contruí a GUI da imagem a partir de uma exemplo do livro da faculdade, porém o botão salvar não tem nenhum funcionalidade. E peço auxilio para implementar no botão salvar algum código que salve os dados informados em uma tabela.

[image: GUI construída a partir de um exemplo.]

// classe principal

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TestCap1{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ClientFrame fClient = new ClientFrame();

        fClient.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fClient.setSize(530,260);
        fClient.setVisible(true);
    }   
}
```

// classe secundária

```
import javax.swing.*;

import javax.swing.border.*;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import java.awt.Font;

import java.awt.event.*;


public class ClientFrame extends JFrame {

    private JMenuItem[] menuItemCliente;
    private JMenuItem[] menuItemAjuda;
    private JLabel[] labels;
    private JTextField[] fields;
    private JLabel titulo;
    private JPanel panelTitulo, panelCadastro;
    private JButton[] botoes;
    private JPanel panelBotoes, panelBase;
    private JLabel status;

    public ClientFrame()
    {
        super("Cadastro de clientes");

        createMenu();
        createForm();
        createBase();
        configAction();
    }

    //Metodo para criar menu
    private void createMenu()
    {
        //Cria menu cliente
        JMenu menuCliente = new JMenu("Cliente");
        menuCliente.setMnemonic('C');

        menuItemCliente = new JMenuItem[3];

        //Cria item novo do menu cliente
        menuItemCliente[0] = new JMenuItem("Novo");
        menuItemCliente[0].setMnemonic('N');
        menuCliente.add(menuItemCliente[0]);

        //Cria separador
        menuCliente.addSeparator();

        //Cria item salvar do cliente
        menuItemCliente[1] = new JMenuItem("Salvar");
        menuItemCliente[1].setMnemonic('S');
        menuCliente.add(menuItemCliente[1]);

        //Cria separador
        menuCliente.addSeparator();

        //Cria item fechar do cliente
        menuItemCliente[2] = new JMenuItem("Fechar");
        menuItemCliente[2].setMnemonic('F');
        menuCliente.add(menuItemCliente[2]);

        //Cria separador
        menuCliente.addSeparator();

        //Cria menu ajuda
        JMenu menuAjuda = new JMenu("Ajuda");
        menuAjuda.setMnemonic('A');

        menuItemAjuda = new JMenuItem[1];

        //Cria item novo do menu ajuda
        menuItemAjuda[0] = new JMenuItem("Sobre...");
        menuItemAjuda[0].setMnemonic('o');
        menuAjuda.add(menuItemAjuda[0]);

        //Cria barra de menu
        JMenuBar barra = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(barra);
        barra.add(menuCliente);
        barra.add(menuAjuda);       

    }

    private void createForm()
    {
        //Cria layout
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //cria panel título
        panelTitulo = new JPanel();
        panelTitulo.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        titulo = new JLabel("Cadastro de Cliente");
        titulo.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        panelTitulo.add(titulo);
        add(panelTitulo, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        //Cria panel cadastro
        panelCadastro = new JPanel();
        panelCadastro.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        //Labels
        labels = new JLabel[8];
        labels[0] = new JLabel("Nome");
        labels[1] = new JLabel("Endereco");
        labels[2] = new JLabel("Bairro");
        labels[3] = new JLabel("Cidade");
        labels[4] = new JLabel("Estado");
        labels[5] = new JLabel("Telefone");
        labels[6] = new JLabel("Celular");
        labels[7] = new JLabel("Email");

        //Fields
        fields = new JTextField[8];
        fields[0] = new JTextField(42);
        fields[1] = new JTextField(40);
        fields[2] = new JTextField(13);
        fields[3] = new JTextField(13);
        fields[4] = new JTextField(6);
        fields[5] = new JTextField(8);
        fields[6] = new JTextField(8);
        fields[7] = new JTextField(15);

        for(int j = 0; j < fields.length; j++)
        {
            panelCadastro.add(labels[j]);
            panelCadastro.add(fields[j]);
        }

        add(panelCadastro, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

    private void createBase()
    {
        //cria panel base
        panelBase = new JPanel();
        panelBase.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //cria panel botoes
        panelBotoes = new JPanel();
        panelBotoes.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));

        botoes = new JButton[2];
        botoes[0] = new JButton("Salvar");
        botoes[1] = new JButton("Fechar");

        panelBotoes.add(botoes[0]);
        panelBotoes.add(botoes[1]);
        panelBase.add(panelBotoes, BorderLayout.EAST);

        //Criar barra de status
        status = new JLabel("Barra de status...");
        status.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        status.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
        panelBase.add(status, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        add(panelBase, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }

    private class NovoHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            for(int i = 0; 1 < fields.length; i++)
            {
                fields[i].setText("");
            }
        }
    }

    private class SalvaHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            status.setText("Cliente salvo");
        }
    }

    private class FechaHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    private class SobreHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Construcao GUI", "Sobre", 
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
    }   

    private void configAction()
    {
        SalvaHandler salvaHandler = new SalvaHandler();
        FechaHandler fechaHandler = new FechaHandler();
        NovoHandler novoHandler = new NovoHandler();
        SobreHandler sobreHandler = new SobreHandler();

        botoes[0].addActionListener(salvaHandler);
        botoes[1].addActionListener(fechaHandler);

        menuItemCliente[0].addActionListener(novoHandler);
        menuItemCliente[1].addActionListener(salvaHandler);
        menuItemCliente[2].addActionListener(fechaHandler);

        menuItemAjuda[0].addActionListener(sobreHandler);

    }
}
```

Comment: Olá, Bruno. Seja bem-vindo. Coloque o código que usou para gerar essa tela.

Comment: Não coloquei porque achei que ia ficar muito extenso.

Comment: O que de fato você quer salvar? Sua duvida não está muito clara. Clique em [edit] e elabore melhor o texto da pergunta, ta meio confuso.

Comment: Pra adicionar uma função quando o botão é clicado, tu tem que dar uma olhada em `Listener`, tem de todo tipo. Um deles é para cliques.